# Create Thread for Method in Unreferenced DLL C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dll

Good day,

My goal is to create a program(windows service, atm it is just a console application) in C# that uses .dll 's that are not referenced and creating threads for methods in the .dll 's.

In other words: I want to create a program that starts threads for methods of unknown .dll's

For example, I have my .dll called testdll.dll which contains a method cWrite()
With my main program I want to create a thread for cWrite(), but the .dll is not referenced.

Currently my code looks as follows:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("testdll.dll");
var aClass = assembly.GetType("testdll.Class1");
dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(aClass);

Thread t1 = new Thread(instance.cWrite());
```

I am getting the error:
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object' at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T 0 arg0) at testService.Program.Main() in C:...\Program.cs:line 85

I know there are various ways to use unreferenced dll's, but creating a thread for a method in one of those dll's is what I am struggling with.

Any help is appreciated,
Regards
Jeff

Comment: Just wrap `instance.cWrite` in a method of your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply: `Thread t1 = new Thread(() => instance.cWrite());` as a `Thread` constructor requires a delegate to invoke while you are passing a result of the `cWrite()` (which is `void`) to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use MEF? You can set the search directories for .dlls and then place any .dll you'd like in there. The only thing you would need to include in your code is the interface when you consume the object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx

Example Common Interface needed for export and import:

```
interface IMyMEFExample
{
    public string HelloFromMEF();
}
```

Example Exported Class:

```
[Export(typeof(IMyMEFExample))]
public class MyExportedMEFClass : IMyMEFExample
{
    public string HelloFromMEF()
    {
        return "Hello from MEF!";
    }
}
```

Example of MEF Consumption:

```
class ImportMEFExample
{
    [Import(typeof(IMyMEFExample))]
    private IMyMEFExample importedMEF;

    public ImportMEFExample()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(importedMEF.HelloFromMEF());
    }
}
```